# Write a variable inside a XML tag with xquery flwor expression

Tags: xml, xquery, flwor

Does someone guru xquery?

I have a XQuery FLWOR expression:

```
<dg:segment xsi:type="dg:SegmentEauType">
{
for $attr_name in fme:get-list-attribute("_att{}._attr_name")
return <attribut name="{$attr_name}">value</attribut>
}
</dg:segment>
```

that produce

```
<dg:segment xsi:type="dg:SegmentEauType">
    <attribut name="DIAMETREM_R">value</attribut>
    <attribut name="PROVENANCEDONNEE_R">value</attribut>
    <!-- etc... -->
</dg:segment>
```

How can I get that XML node?

```
<dg:segment xsi:type="dg:SegmentEauType">
    <DIAMETREM_R>value<DIAMETREM_R>
    <PROVENANCEDONNEE_R>value<PROVENANCEDONNEE_R>
    <!-- etc... -->
</dg:segment>
```

I've tried, but I got an error.

```
for $attr_name in fme:get-list-attribute("_att{}._attr_name")
return <{$attr_name}>value</{$attr_name}>
```

Don't matter about fme:get-list-attribute function...

Many Tx!

Comment: What “error” did you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<dg:segment xsi:type="dg:SegmentEauType">
{
for $attr_name in fme:get-list-attribute("_att{}._attr_name")
return element { $attr_name } { 'value' }
}
</dg:segment>
```

Comment: you can try this solution live at http://try.zorba.io/queries/xquery/%2BZDmCM7MapDlHFhzLgN56B9%2FV7Q%3D